# file_get_contents with query string to get data for particular id

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I have two files, `register.php, query.php`. I want functionality like from `register.php` page I can display the data for particular id, which is processed in `query.php`.

**register.php**

```
echo file_get_contents('query.php?id=1');  
echo file_get_contents('query.php?id=2'); 
.
.
echo file_get_contents('query.php?id=14'); 
echo file_get_contents('query.php?id=15');
```

**query.php**

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
$id = $_GET['id'];
switch ($id) {
    case 1:
    $query1 = mysql_query("select * from tblname where id=$id");
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
            $file = $row1['type'];
            $file_type_name = "qsg";
            $header = $row1['title'];
            $paragraph_description =  $row1['description'];
            include '../../../print.php';
}
       // break;
    case 2:
    $query1 = mysql_query("select * from tblname where id=$id");
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
                $file_type = $row1['type'];
                $file_name = "email_intro";
                $header = $row1['title'];
                $abstract = $row1['description'];
                include '../../../email.php';
}
      // break;

// default:
//        echo "other";

}
}
```

I have to show data from the database for all id. I am not getting how should I get data for particular id which may vary, and show it on register.php page.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: file_get_contents() doesn't get the page output it gets the files inner content such as php/html  you may want to use cURL

Comment: @ Diyar Baban: I am new to cURL. How I can use that in above situation?

Comment: on php's docs there is almost everything you may need to know about cURL http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php